# Aviso: "Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable"

Tags: c#, .net, warnings, resharper, enumerable

Estava fazendo umas operações onde faço o uso de coleções. Numa dessas eu precisei pegar um intervalo (`range`) de números e fiz o seguinte:

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 4);
```

E depois tentei fazer algo como

```
var primeiro = range.First();
```

Porém, o Resharper fica me dando o aviso

> Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable

Se eu fizer converter a variável `range` para uma lista o aviso some.

Qual é o motivo do Resharper mostrar este aviso e o que ele quer dizer?

Comment: Estou saindo mas a resposta parece estar aqui http://stackoverflow.com/q/8240844/221800

Comment: O enumerable.rage retorna qual objeto? É um linq no BD?

Comment: Não, ele retorna um `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O motivo é que, ao fazer menção a `range` ou a qualquer método de extensão dele, você estará chamando `GetEnumerator()` e iterando de alguma forma sobre ele.

Para listas pequenas como esta, não há muita diferença de performance. A coisa muda com uma enumeração de milhares de registros.

Vamos fundo na dor. Imagine o seguinte:

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000);
```

Ao atribuir a variável, você já criou uma enumeração iterável por 100000 registros. Ao chamar:

```
var primeiro = range.First();
```

Você está chamando `GetEnumerator()` de novo, pois uma enumeração não é uma lista concreta. Tanto que isto dá um erro de compilação:

```
public List<MeuObjeto>() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        yield return MeuObjeto();
    }
}
```

E isto funciona:

```
public IEnumerable<MeuObjeto>() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        yield return MeuObjeto();
    }
}
```

Imagine agora o custo desta última função sobre 100000 registros. E que no seu caso, ela é executada 2 vezes.

É por isso que o ReSharper sugere que você concretize a lista. Ele não sabe o que tem por trás, mas supõe o pior caso sempre.

Answer (score 2):

O problema com o Enumerable.Range, é que toda vez que tiver alguma iteração este código vai ser chamado e a query executada.

Se você converte para lista, após a primeira execução o resultado vai ficar em cacheado em memória e depois o restante vai ser computado em cima dela.

No seu caso, se você fizer por exemplo:

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 4); 
var soma = range.Sum();
var itens = range.Count();
```

A variável range será gerada/executada 2 vezes, se tiver alguma query, a query vai ser rodada 2 vezes e assim por diante...

Fazendo através de uma lista, a variável "range" só seria executada uma vez.

Fonte: https://helloacm.com/c-linq-possible-multiple-enumeration-of-ienumerable-resharper/

Comment: Quer dizer que ao fazer `range.Count()` o intervalo será gerado novamente para fazer o `Count()`?

Comment: Exatamente, por isso o ideal é converter para lista.