# EntityFramework .AsEnumerable() ou .ToList()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lista, enumerable

Em um dos projetos que peguei vi o seguinte código, que implementa um método de listagem de dados de uma determinada entidade, porém esta listagem é utilizada apenas para leitura:

```
/// <summary>
/// Listar todas entidades
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public IList<T> ListarTodos()
{
    return ctxContexto.Set<T>().ToList();
}
```

O método funciona perfeitamente, a minha dúvida é com relação a desempenho e boas práticas de programação com o EntityFramework. Há um tempo atrás vi uma pergunta aqui no SOpt que falava da [diferença entre IEnumerable, IQueryable e IList](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17284/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ienumerable-iqueryable-e-list).

Baseado na questão acima citada, pensei "Se meu método retornar um `List<T>` estarei dando à pessoa que chamar o método a possibilidade de inserir ou remover itens da lista", o que não é correto, visto que a minha lista é somente leitura.

```
List<Cliente> lista = new Servico<Cliente>().ListarTodos();
lista.RemoveAt(0)
lista.Add(new Cliente());
```

Mudei o retorno do método para IEnumerable conforme abaixo:

```
/// <summary>
/// Listar todas entidades
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public IEnumerable<T> ListarTodos()
{
    return ctxContexto.Set<T>().AsEnumerable();
}
```

O código acima também funcionou, mais toda vez que chamo o método ListarTodos, se eu realizar mais de uma verificação com o item da lista no mesmo contexto de código:

```
List<Cliente> lista = new Servico<Cliente>().ListarTodos();
int count = lista .Count();
Console.WriteLine(count);
Console.WriteLine(lista .Any());
```

É apresentada a mensagem pelo Resharper.

> Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable

Isto também já foi tratado em uma [pergunta aqui do SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100257/aviso-possible-multiple-enumeration-of-ienumerable) e eu entendi o porque da mesma, as minhas dúvidas são:

***Qual é a melhor abordagem neste caso?***

***Alguma delas me trará algum benefício de desempenho?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Qual é a melhor abordagem neste caso?

Continuar a usar `List<>`, que é a resolução em memória de uma enumeração. Uma enumeração pode ser uma função ou método, cujo desempenho é pior.

Se você deseja que a lista seja somente-leitura (o que não entendi, porque uma lista pode sim ser alterada dentro do fluxo de uma requisição), deve usar [`AsReadOnly()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/e78dcd75(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
/// <summary>
/// Listar todas entidades
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public IReadOnlyCollection<T> ListarTodos()
{
    return ctxContexto.Set<T>().ToList().AsReadOnly();
}
```

> Alguma delas me trará algum benefício de desempenho?

A forma com que você está usando, não. Usar repositório sobre repositório, [além de injustificado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696), traz penalidades desnecessárias de desempenho.

Comment: "(o que não entendi, porque uma lista pode sim ser alterada dentro do fluxo de uma requisição)". Posso não ter me expressado bem, mais o contexto da minha aplicação exige que este pedaço seja somente leitura. No meu caso é uma regra do meu negócio.

Comment: Então use uma lista somente-leitura. Se `List<>` pode ser alterada, ela não é a estrutura de dados que você precisa.

Comment: Discordo do amigo @cigano-morrison-mendez, pois List é uma Classe onde implementa todas estas interfaces:

**IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>**

Answer (score -1):

List é uma Classe onde implementa todas estas interfaces:

**IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, IEnumerable, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList, IReadOnlyCollection**

1. Para iteração somente 1 vez com o resultado, use a interface de IEnumerable ou IReadOnlyCollection
2. Para mais de uma iteração, converta seu enumerable para lista: `.ToList()` no início do escopo do método onde é chamado o método com retorno de IEnumerable!

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Esta resposta está incorreta. [O fato de `List` implementar `IReadOnlyList` é justamente para que o método `AsReadOnly()` seja viável](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx). Além disso, o uso de repositório em cima de EF traz claras penalidades de desempenho, por forçar `TABLE SCAN`s desnecessários em memória.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez o  que discordei da sua resposta foi: 

"Continuar a usar List<>, que é a resolução em memória de uma enumeração. Uma enumeração pode ser uma função ou método, cujo desempenho é pior."

Quando List implementa IEnumerable, desde quando um retorno de IEnumerable terá desempenho pior do que toda uma classe que implementa várias interfaces? Posso estar errado, mas o princípio da lógica não me permite entender isto! Se tiveres alguma explicação para me convencer do contrário agradeceria!

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` pede a implementação de `GetEnumerator()`, que é um método, e não uma classe em memória. O percurso para leitura dos elementos será, no mínimo, `O(n)`.

Comment: Além disso, o comportamento de enumerações no Entity Framework faz, na resolução dessa enumeração, a execução de uma sentença SQL (na conversão de `IQueryable`, de um `DbSet`, em `IEnumerable`, o que também piora o desempenho). A melhor prática, para o autor da pergunta, seria o método ser `public IQueryable<T> ListarTodos()`, e [explico aqui porque a prática é simplesmente inútil](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696).

Comment: Agora  sim... sobre o IQueryable nem se discute, pois efetivamente não executou o SQL! Mas entre List e IEnumerable, fico com IEnumerable como retorno de listas e não de enitdades!